# Error al invocar una variable, declarada en una función

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

Es un formulario sencillo en la cual, si algún elemento input no tiene contenido, cambiara su color de fondo y un aviso `setCustomValidity()`. Pero en la consola aparece el error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: apellido is not defined`. Creo que se debe de dentro de esa función (`validar()`), no está definidida la variable `apellido`, por lo cual no reconoce su valor.
Pero la variable se encuentra definida en la función `comenzar()`, ¿existe la manera en la cual pueda reconocer esta variable?

```js
function comenzar () {

            var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre');
            var apellido = document.getElementById('Apellido');

            nombre.addEventListener("input", validar, false);
            apellido.addEventListener("input", validar, false);
            validar();
        }

        function validar() {

               if(nombre.value=="" && apellido=="") {

                nombre.setCustomValidity('Introduce nombre o apellido');
                nombre.style.backgroundColor =  'red';
                apellido.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

            } else {
                nombre.setCustomValidity("");
                nombre.style.backgroundColor = 'initial';
                apellido.style.backgroundColor = 'initial';
            }
        }
        
        window.addEventListener('load', comenzar, false);
```

```css
    table {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #f96;
            width: 25%;
            margin: auto;
            border: 2px dashed #f30;
        }

        td {
            padding: 15px;
        }
```

```html
<section>
        <form action="get" name="registro_usario">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nombre:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Apellido:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Apellido" id="Apellido"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Edad:</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="Edad" id="Edad" min="1" max="100"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="Enviar"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si exactamente es por eso....

**apellido** y **nombre** son locales al declararlas dentro de una funcion...

declaralas fuera para que sean globales

```
var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre');
var apellido = document.getElementById('Apellido');

function comenzar () {
...
}
```

Piensa que todo codigo situado fuera de una función siempre se ejecutará cuando se importe  o se añada al archivo HTML.